# How to prevent Logstash sending multiple log files to Elastic?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am using the following 6.x stack:

Filebeat -> Logstash -> Elastic -> Kibana

I am trying to configure filebeat/logstash to send a specific logfile only to Elastic. Right now it appears to be sending everything.

When I look in Kibana I see most messages from /var/log/messages.

Filebeat config:

```
filebeat.inputs:

- type: log

  enabled: true

  paths:
    #- /var/log/*.log
    - /var/log/nginx/app.access.log
    #- c:\programdata\elasticsearch\logs\*

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
  index: logstash
```

Logstash Config:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5044"
    }
}

filter {
     grok {
        match => {"message" => '%{IP:client} - %{USERNAME:username} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \"(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})\" %{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-) %{QS:referrer} %{QS:agent} %{DATA: http_x_forwarded_for} %{DATA:gzip_ratio} rt=%{NUMBER:request_time} uct=%{NUMBER:upstream_connect_time} uht=%{NUMBER:upstream_header_time} urt=%{NUMBER:upstream_response_time} %{NUMBER:user_id}'}
    }
    grok {
        match => {"request" => "\/dataset\/%{NUMBER:dataset_id}"}
    }
    kv {
        source => "request"
        field_split => "&?"
        transform_key => "lowercase"
    }
    if "/search" in [request] and [q] {
        mutate {add_field => {"search_action" => "search" }}
    }
    if [request] =~ "\/dataset\/%{NUMBER:dataset_id}" {
        mutate {add_field => {"dataset_id" => dataset_id}}
    }
    mutate {
       convert => {
           "user_id" => "integer"
           "dataset_id" => "integer"
       }
       # lowercase => [ "request" ]
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
       codec => "json"
       hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

With this configuration I should only be getting /var/log/nginx/app.access.log data sent to elastic?

Within Kibana I see all activity from multiple log files:

/var/log/messages
/var/log/secure

Any ideas why this happening as I can't really find any solutions to this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe an old copy of filebeat is still running?

Comment: configurartion error , or old copy of config is running , kill filebeat and start it with new config

Comment: There is only once instance of filebeat running and I tried a new config. Still the same problem.

Comment: I figured out the problem. It was one of the filebeat modules at /etc/filebeat/modules.d/system.yml